# Trigger scheduled query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, triggers, scheduled-tasks, data-partitioning

I have a partitioned table (bigquery) and records are streamed for each date multiple times during a few days period, eg: records for 02.06.2022 are streamed on 03.06, 04.06, 05.06 and etc.

Is there a way that these updates can trigger a scheduled query and insert some of the new records (based on certain criteria) to another table? Maybe using the last modified field from the table's details somehow?

The reason: we can't wait until all updates are done before using the data that we already have but at the same time we need to have all the data that is available after the first run.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've not used bigquery myself, but it looks like [they have a way to schedule queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries), if this might be what you're looking for?

Comment: I already have set the scheduled query, but i need it to run only over the tables that have been updated since the previous run. I have already found a way to do it, thank you!

Comment: @T.B., please don't leave the question without answers. In the previous comment, you have mentioned that you have found a way to do it. So, can you post an answer with your findings? It helps community members with their research as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what i did was use TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) in the where statement of the scheduled query. I made the where statement to check the last_modified_time of a list of tables that i needed. If it was after the previous run, then the query would insert the new records.